# Django CMS reverse-admin

Tags: django, django-cms

I am very new to django CMS, I am trying to add `toolbar` of my blog.

This is my `cms_toolbar.py` file

```
from cms.toolbar_base import CMSToolbar
from cms.toolbar_pool import toolbar_pool
from blog.models import BlogPluginModel
from cms.utils.urlutils import admin_reverse


class PollToolbar(CMSToolbar):

    def populate(self):
        menu = self.toolbar.get_or_create_menu(
            'blog_pluginmodel',  # a unique key for this menu
            'blog',                        # the text that should appear in the menu
            )
        menu.add_modal_item(
            name='Add a new blog',                # name of the new menu item
            url=admin_reverse('blog_pluginmodel'),  # the URL it should open with
        )

toolbar_pool.register(PollToolbar)
```

But fires me an error below:

```
NoReverseMatch at /en/
Reverse for 'blog_pluginmodel' not found. 'blog_pluginmodel' is not a valid view function or pattern name.
```

I am not getting how can i fix this.. Can anyone help me in this case?

What is reverse-admin actually?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a link to the [documentation](http://docs.django-cms.org/en/latest/introduction/06-toolbar.html#the-complete-cms-toolbars-py), and here's the [source code](https://github.com/divio/django-cms/blob/develop/cms/utils/urlutils.py#L95).

What `admin_reverse` does is resolve the admin (list/add/edit) view of a django model to display it in the djangocms modal.

In your case, something like this should work:

```py
admin_reverse('blog_pluginmodel_changelist')
```

or

```py
admin_reverse('blog_pluginmodel_add')
```

In a more abstract way: `reverse_admin('appname_modelname_adminview')`.

P.S.: I'm not sure if a plugin model is really what you want to make accessible through the toolbar, but that's another discussion.